# Caching temporary data - PostgreSQL and Mongo

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, caching

I have some data from an API I need to cache. This data I want invalidated after X days, but I want it available locally to save time querying and compiling things for the end user.

Presently I have a PostgreSQL database. I want to keep this around because there's permanent data like user records I don't want to put in Mongo (unless you guys can convince me otherwise). I really have nothing against Mongo, but I can normalize some things with users and the only way I could think to do it without massive amounts of duplication is via PostgreSQL.

Now my API data is flat, and in JSON. I don't need to create any sort of link to any other table and it has a field that I can use as a key pretty easily. My idea is to literally "throw" the data into a Mongo instance and query as needed, invaliding every X days. This also offers some persistence should the server go down for whatever reason.

So my questions to you guys are this. Is this a good use case for Mongo over memcached? Should I just memcached the raw data instead? If you guys do suggest Mongo, should I move my users table and the relations over to Mongo as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of thing Redis is really good for. Redis, possibly with selective cache invalidation via PostgreSQL's LISTEN and NOTIFY, is a pretty low pain way to manage caching.

Another option is to use `UNLOGGED` tables in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Could you expand a little on UNLOGGED tables? I have never heard of them. Also, since you seem to be knowledgeable on Redis - how hard is it to get Redis and PostgreSQL to work together?

Comment: You usually want your app co-ordinating things, rather than plugging Pg directly into Redis, though you can do that too (see `redis_fdw` - but I haven't used it myself). You'd usually use it like a smarter memcached. As for UNLOGGED ... see the documentation; it's basically a volatile table that uses less resources to insert/update/delete because it's not recorded in WAL, but it isn't crash safe so the data is lost if PostgreSQL or the server crashes.